# How to iterate json data after successful AJAX POST to PHP file?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cart

I have created a session cart but i am not sure how to iterate the response data coming from PHP after successful AJAX POST. Actually, i need total quantity and price of products that exist in $_SESSION['cart']. What i have done so far:

PHP

```
<?php

session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $product_ids = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'product_id');
    $index = count($_SESSION['cart']);

    //if product has not been already in cart
    if (!in_array($_POST['product_id'], $product_ids)) {

        $product = array(
            'product_id' => $_POST['product_id'] + 0,
            'product_quantity' => $_POST['product_quantity'] + 0,
            'product_price' => $_POST['product_price'] + 0
        );

        $_SESSION['cart'][++$index] = $product;
    }

    //if product exists update it's quantity and total price
    else {

        $new_quantity = $_POST['product_quantity'] + $_SESSION['cart'][$index]['product_quantity'];
        $new_price = $_POST['product_price'] + $_SESSION['cart'][$index]['product_price'];

        $product = array(
            'product_id' => $_POST['product_id'] + 0,
            'product_quantity' => $new_quantity,
            'product_price' => $new_price
        );

        $_SESSION['cart'][$index] = $product;
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    
    echo json_encode($_SESSION['cart']);
}
```

JS

```
    $('.btn-cart').click(function () {

        var product_id = parseInt(this.id);
        var product_quantity = parseInt($(this).closest("div").prev().find("input[type='number']").val());
        var product_price = parseFloat($(this).closest("div").find("input[type='hidden']").val());

 
        $.post('../../session_cart.php', {
            product_id: product_id,
            product_quantity: product_quantity,
            product_price: product_price
        })
            .done(function (data) {

                console.log(data);

            })
            .fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
                var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                console.log('Error - ' + errorMessage);
            });
    });
```

All ideas or suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
  $('.btn-cart').click(function () {

        var product_id = parseInt(this.id);
        var product_quantity = parseInt($(this).closest("div").prev().find("input[type='number']").val());
        var product_price = parseFloat($(this).closest("div").find("input[type='hidden']").val());

 
        $.post('../../session_cart.php', {
            product_id: product_id,
            product_quantity: product_quantity,
            product_price: product_price
        })
            .done(function (data) {
                var total_price= 0;
                var total_quantity = 0;
                var json_data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                for (key in json_data){
                  total_price += Number(json_data[key]['product_price']);
                  total_quantity += Number(json_data[key]['product_quantity']);
            }

                console.log(total_quantity);
                console.log(total_price);

            })
            .fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
                var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                console.log('Error - ' + errorMessage);
            });
    });
```

Parsed the `data` coming and stored it in `json_data`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Data need to be stringified for some reason so i edited your solution ```var json_data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));```

Comment: Oh yeah :-). Hope it helps with what you are looking for